# While trying to access CMS data using ConnectApi.ManagedContent throwing an error like 'You don't have access to this channel.'

Tags: apex, experience-cloud, lwr, salesforce-cms

[image]

While trying to access CMS data on LWR site(Not Aura) using an Apex class with ConnectApi.ManagedContent, throwing an error like 'You don't have access to this channel.'

Apex code:

```
String networkId = Network.getNetworkId();
            ConnectApi.ManagedContentVersionCollection contentCollection = ConnectApi.ManagedContent.getManagedContentByContentKeys(
                networkId,
                new List<String> { contentId },
                0,
                1,
                language,
                filterby,
                false
            );                
            return contentCollection.items[0].contentNodes;
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Can you pass the networkId parameter value based on this [article](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000386512&type=1) and see if the error persists?

Comment: It's not solved the issue.

Answer (score -1):

In CMS ..normally you have 2 types of Workspace one is **CMS workspace** and other one is **Enhanced CMS workspace**...so if you are using LWR sites you need to make sure you are using **Enhanced CMS workspace** the other one i.e **CMS workspace** is not supported in LWR sites.